# How to purge Front Door Standard/Premium (Preview) endpoint using code

Tags: purge, azure-front-door

In the subscription (name: `test-subscription`) in the resource group (name: `test-resource-group`), I created *Front Door Standard/Premium (Preview)* (name: `test-front-door-profile`) with endpoint `test-front-door-profile-endpoint.z01.azurefd.net` and added new endpoint (endpoint name: `test-endpoint.z01.azurefd.net`).

For example: I created a request: `https://test-endpoint.z01.azurefd.net/test/pictures/abcdefghi.jpeg`. How can I purge `test-endpoint.z01.azurefd.net/test/pictures/*` using code?

I tried with this code, and different variants of `contentPaths`

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.FrontDoor;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.FrontDoor.Models;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.Rest;
...

        public async Task PurgeContentAsync()
        {
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority);
            var credential = new ClientCredential(ClientId, ClientSecret);
            var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(_resource, credential);

            var frontDoor = new FrontDoorManagementClient(new TokenCredentials(authResult.AccessToken)) { SubscriptionId = _subscriptionId };

            var contentPaths = new List<string> { "/test-endpoint.z01.azurefd.net/test/pictures/*" };
            var contentFilePaths = new PurgeParameters(contentPaths);

            await frontDoor.Endpoints.BeginPurgeContentAsync("test-resource-group", "test-front-door-profile", contentFilePaths);
        }
```

but I always get exception:

```
The exception Microsoft.Azure.Management.FrontDoor.Models.ErrorResponseException was unhandled on the service and could not be serialized for transferring to the client.
Detailed Remote Exception Information: Microsoft.Azure.Management.FrontDoor.Models.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'
```

I tried with Microsoft.Azure.Management.Cdn library but I am getting back the same exception.

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?